# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'html'

Tags: python-3.x, facebook, screen-scraping, non-type

I am using the following code to scrape Facebook posts from a page. It starts scraping posts and then after five or six posts are scraped, it gives me an error. (The original library could be found here: https://github.com/kevinzg/facebook-scraper")

The code:

```
from facebook_scraper import get_posts
import csv
import pandas as pd
import sys
non_bmp_map = dict.fromkeys(range(0x10000, sys.maxunicode + 1), 0xfffd)
csvFile = open('nintendo.csv', 'a')
csvWriter = csv.writer(csvFile)
for post in get_posts('nintendo', pages=100):
    print(post['text'].translate(non_bmp_map))
    csvWriter.writerow([post['text'].encode('utf-8')])
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\codes\Fb2.py", line 10, in <module>
    for post in get_posts('nintendo', pages=100):
  File "C:\Users\Python37-32\facebook_scraper.py", line 60, in get_posts
    yield _extract_post(article)
  File "C:\Users\Python37-32\facebook_scraper.py", line 95, in _extract_post
    'likes': _find_and_search(article, 'footer', _likes_regex, _parse_int) or 0,
  File "C:\Users\Python37-32\facebook_scraper.py", line 213, in _find_and_search
    match = pattern.search(container.html)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'html'
```

Comment: container is `None`

Comment: But how come None if it already scraped some posts?

Answer (score 1):

```py
import csv
import sys

from facebook_scraper import get_posts
non_bmp_map = dict.fromkeys(range(0x10000, sys.maxunicode + 1), 0xfffd)
csvFile = open('nintendo.csv', 'a')
csvWriter = csv.writer(csvFile)

try:
    for post in get_posts('nintendo', pages=100):

        print(post['text'].translate(non_bmp_map)) 
        csvWriter.writerow([post['text'].encode('utf-8')])

except AttributeError:
    print("No more posts to get")
```

Comment: Please format your code properly, [click here to learn how](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).